# How to get Code Page by Language-Culture?

Tags: c#, localization

Does anyone aware of C# API to accept Language-Culture and return corresponding Code Page? For instance, if I call

```
MagicClass.GetCodePage("ru-RU")
```

I would get

```
1251
```

If this was answered before, please drop me a link.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [`TextInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.aspx) class (accessible via [`CultureInfo.TextInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.textinfo.aspx)) contains code pages:

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-RU");
Console.WriteLine(cultureInfo.TextInfo.ANSICodePage); // 1251
```

It sounds like you want ANSI code pages, but you can also get Mac, OEM, and EBCDIC versions.

Comment: Thanks! Accepting your answer as it is correct and exhaustive!

Answer (score 2):

new CultureInfo("ru-Ru").TextInfo.ANSICodePage